# ajax post method error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

In the following example I am able to pass JSON representation of the country list and display it but I cannot display the message "Could not find any countries". Could you please check the code below:

Controller:

```
if ($this->model_abc->did_get_country_list($user_id)) {             
        $country["results"]= $this->model_abc->did_get_country_list($user_id);          
            echo json_encode($country);         
        }
        else {      
        $country = array('message' => "Could not find any countries" );
            echo json_encode($country);     
        }
```

JS file:

```
$.post('cont/get_country_list', function (country) {
    $.each(country.results, function(i, res) {
        var item = $('<div>'),               
        title = $('<h3>');
        title.text(res);
        item.append(title);
        item.appendTo($("#country_list_is_got"));
    });   
}, 
       "json").error(function() { 
           $( "#country_list_is_not_got").text(country.message);
       });
```

**Update:**

I changed my code as following and now I get thise error from console: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**.

JS file:

```
$.post('cont/get_country_list', function (country) {
    if (country.message !== undefined) {
        $( "#country_list_is_not_got").text(country.message);
    } else {
        $.each(country.results, function(i, res) {
             var item = $('<div>'),               
                 title = $('<h3>');
                 title.text(res);
                 item.append(title);
                 item.appendTo($("#country_list_is_got"));
        });  


 }
});
```

Comment: So what's `$user_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error-function is only called when the server responses with a 500-HTTP code (or 404, 403 or a timeout etc.). You are returning just valid JSON with a normal HTTP status-code, so the success-function is called. Within that success-function you should check if there was a message or not:

```
$.post('cont/get_country_list', function (data) {
    if (data.message !== undefined) {
        $( "#country_list_is_not_got").text(data.message);
    } else {
        $.each(country.results, function(i, res) {
             var item = $('<div>'),               
                 title = $('<h3>');
                 title.text(res);
                 item.append(title);
                 item.appendTo($("#country_list_is_got"));
        });   
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed my question. Could you please check it?

Comment: Looks like botch `country.message` and `country.results` are undefined. Did you check the server-response of that JSON-request in the web developer tool / console (F12)?

Comment: I got these results: **{"results": ["USA", "Canada"]}** and this result for else **{"message":"Could not find any countries."}**

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting an error reply code in the case where no countries are found, so it's not treated as an error by jQuery.

```
else {
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Error");
    $country = array('message' => "Could not find any countries" );
    echo json_encode($country);
}
```

Also, your error function needs to get the data from its parameter:

```
.error(function(xhr) {
    country = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
    $( "#country_list_is_not_got").text(country.message);
});
```